# Internet connection not working with Linux OS

Tags: linux, windows, wireless-networking

I am using a D-Link GLB-502T router at my place which provides me with a cable with an RJ-45 plug. I put this into a D-Link DIR-605L Wifi router to access internet wirelessly.

All is fine till I am using Windows 7. However, the problem starts when I switch to Linux. I am unable to connect to the Internet when I am working with Linux. This does not work irrespective of whether I am trying to connect wirelessly or via a cable. However, I am able to connect to other systems on the LAN under my wifi router.

Can anyone suggest what is wrong with my system?

P.S: I am using Linux Mint.

Comment: Can you ping the ip of your router? What is the output of the commands of "ip addr ls" and "ip route ls"?

Comment: @PeterHorvath :

Output is too long to post in a comment here. Hence posting it splitting in 3 comments:-

nikit@meanmachine ~ $ ip addr ls

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether d4:be:d9:52:cc:62 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

Comment: 3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 68:5d:43:fd:70:f5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.101/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global wlan0
    inet6 fe80::6a5d:43ff:fefd:70f5/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Comment: nikit@meanmachine ~ $ ip route ls

default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0  proto static 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlan0  scope link  metric 1000 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.101  metric 2

Comment: Here is the cause: "eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP>". Your ethernet connection is down. You are accessing your LAN through your wifi connection. Turn your lan down, and make a reconnect with your ethernet connection, what happens?

Comment: @PeterHorvath How?

Comment: @PeterHorvath I did try that. It is still the same. Unable to connect to internet. I am able to access the router though by hitting 192.168.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Successful local(same LAN under AP) communication means there is no problem on wired/wireless connection it self. So I can guess wrong configuration of GW or DNS on linux box.

If your local LAN use DHCP, check GW and DNS was auto configured or manual, and has right value.

anyway I think this Q is off topic.